# C# Forms and Immutable Classes

Tags: c#, forms

I understand how and why to create immutable classes, however, does the same rules apply to WinForms and Subforms? Allow me to elaborate.

Main Form:

```
private void addNewEmployeeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int empcount = (comboEmail.Items.Count - 1);
            Employee retrive = null;



            using (Add addEmp = new Add(empcount))
            {
                DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
                addEmp.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
                dr = addEmp.ShowDialog();

                if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    retrive = addEmp.GetEmployee;
                    addtoTextFileCombo(retrive);

                }

            }


        }
```

Subform:

```
public partial class Add : Form
    {
        public Employee GetEmployee {get; private set;}
        public int CreateId { get; private set; }

        public Add(int id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CreateId = id;


        }
        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.CreateId++;
                this.GetEmployee = new Employee(CreateId, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtEmail.Text);
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException msg)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);

            }
        }
    }
```

In my subform, I'm using a getter/setter property to create an Employee object and pass it back to my main form. **Is it okay to use a Getter/Setter in my subform the way I did?**

When creating immutable classes, you have readonly variables and use a constructor to set them. You don't use setters at all even if it's private. In this example, Employee is immutable.

Is what i did, bad practice? If so, how do I fix it without losing any of the functionality I have right now.

Comment: I'm a little confused... Are you asking if forms should be immutable? What alternative are you considering for your code that doesn't write to a property in the event?

Comment: I don't know what the alternative is, but in your opinion should the subform be immutable? I don't want to keep developing only to find out, I have done what is considered bad practice. Keep the code the way it is? Continue using the setter the way I have?

Comment: Yeah. Forms by their very nature pretty much are mutable. You often want to add controls, change data, etc. You probably could make them immutable but I don't think you'd gain anything from doing so.

Comment: The employee object itself is immutable, so in your opinion, leave as is correct? I'm doing what is consider proper practice for forms/subforms, right? Even Microsoft uses public setter for form controls

Comment: Question tittle is misleading, while asking for *immutable forms* (between rows) you are in fact simply curious if it's ok to return form value via read-only (for a form caller) property. And it's totally fine. Form instance exists for as long as you have it and it will hold all values of properties until you dispose it. Do it as you are doing it. Another alternative to return value would be using some public place to store it (static class? via configuration? deserializing into a known file? etc.) or as a return value of a method which is used to show form(calls `ShowDialog`)and return result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is bad practice. We regularly use Microsoft's own `OpenFileDialog` (and its sister dialogs) that allow you to call `ShowDialog()` and once user chooses a file and clicks OK button (Open or Save actually), the sub form (the dialog that is) vanishes away and we can still access `FileName` property to get the name of the selected file(s). So it appears to be a standard practice.

Comment: So much so, Microsoft even does it! Even form controls have public getter/setter properties. Thanks for the reassurance.

Answer (score 0):

The mutability of an object should be decided according to the business rules/flow or inherited from the object it represents from the domain universe.

A form per se is not a representation of an object from your applications domain; it is merely a way of visualizing such objects and/or a way of interacting with such objects (either by modifying object state through bounded controls and/or by deleting/creating objects). As such, a form should never be immutable - it has state that is not relevant to your applications domain and that state can and will change without you being able to enforce that.

As examples of such properties you have `Position` which changes whenever user moves the window, `Location` and so on...